# How do I find out if my server is running IMAP?

Tags: centos, imap

How do I find out what IMAP server (if any) is running on a CentOS server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`telnet <servername> imap` and/or `telnet <servername> imaps`. If you get answers then you have IMAP from the Internet. You can also look if it is available only on your server by `telnet localhost imap` and/or `telnet localhost imaps`.

Alternatively you could check if `netstat -a | fgrep imap` returns a line with LISTEN in it. Then the IMAP server is up and running.

Comment: Just for completeness: IMAP is port 143 and IMAPS port 993. And if for some weird reason your machine does not have telnet installed by default it may have nc (netcat) which you can use instead.

Answer (score 4):

If your host is running imap it will most likely be listening on ports 143 or 993. `netstat -p` will tell you which process is listening on what port so if you want to find out which imap server you are running try this:

```
 # netstat -apnn | grep LISTEN | egrep '993|143'
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1777/dovecot    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1777/dovecot
```

In my case I am running dovecot.

Comment: You can use `-l` option instead of `grep LISTEN`.